# Angular 2 xi18n cannot resolve template path outside of component directory

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am trying to use the new xi18n in Angular 2 **version 2.1.1** . When I run the `./node_modules/.bin/ng-xi18n` command  to extract the locales I hit on this error:

> Error: Compilation failed. Resource file not found:
>   C:/Projects/SellPro/javaSolution/branches/work/webapp/sellPro/app/ts/templates/app.component.html
>       at Object.get (C:\Projects\SellPro\javaSolution\branches\work\webapp\sellPro\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\extract_i18n.js:13:23)
>       at DirectiveNormalizer._fetch (C:\Projects\SellPro\javaSolution\branches\work\webapp\sellPro\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13661:45)
>       at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateAsync (C:\Projects\SellPro\javaSolution\branches\work\webapp\sellPro\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13707:23)
>       at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeDirective (C:\Projects\SellPro\javaSolution\branches\work\webapp\sellPro\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13681:46)
>       at C:\Projects\SellPro\javaSolution\branches\work\webapp\sellPro\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\extractor.js:45:64
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at C:\Projects\SellPro\javaSolution\branches\work\webapp\sellPro\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\extractor.js:40:29
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Extractor.extract (C:\Projects\SellPro\javaSolution\branches\work\webapp\sellPro\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\extractor.js:38:15)
>       at extract (C:\Projects\SellPro\javaSolution\branches\work\webapp\sellPro\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\extract_i18n.js:19:35)
>   Extraction failed

Project structure:

[image]

My project structure is with separate **template folder** witch is not inside the **ts** folder. When I track the error i saw that the **urlResolver.resolve** method in **directive_normalizer.js** accepts **moduleUrl** and **templateUrl as params**. Is there any way to change that or just point the xi18n to read from the template directory?